# mod_ssl client certificates on a reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, java, reverse-proxy, mod-ssl, oracle-11g

I am trying to add client certificate authentication on a reverse proxy that proxies an oracle application. Before adding, and if i remove the subsequent code, the oracle application is able to start java, load, and function properly.

When I add the check on either the whole proxy (since it only proxies this application), or to the specific location, the java application doesn't load. These are the added lines:

> SSLVerifyClient require 
>      SSLVerifyDepth 1   
>      SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth

The verification works fine and dandy; its just that adding the check stops the application from loading and not sure why. Any help would be awesome

New info:

I was able to resolve my issue with the failed handshake (it was a spelling error that i didn't notice so the check failed). Now i am running into:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.forms.webutil.common.RegisterWebUtil 
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source) 
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source) 
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source) 
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source) 
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
>   basic: load: class oracle.forms.webutil.common.RegisterWebUtil not found. 
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.forms.webutil.common.RegisterWebUtil 
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) 
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source) 
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) 
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source) 
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source) 
>     at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source) 
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

if i remove the code snippet mentioned in the post though, specially SSLVerifyClient to none or optional, everything works again. I also can't add config=webutil to the end of the link i am using because it already has a config specified.

Comment: Was able to resolve the handshaKe_failure but now I have traversed to a new error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.forms.webutil.common.RegisterWebUtil if i remove the code snippet mentioned in the post though, everything works again. –

Comment: Sorry about that; updated appropriately

Comment: Any potential help? Or more info you need to try to help?